# Never closing re-used SQL service broker conversation

Tags: sql, dialog, queue, service-broker

I am aware that SQL Service broker implementation discourages a fire and forget approach but anything else in my scenario would be an overkill so I am using that scenario.

Anyhow, I am guaranteeing that the sender will never open more than a limited number of conversations (5) and talk to them in round robin fashion. So does the receiver app, it retrieves from these conversations in a round robin fashion as well.

The point is that we never, use more than 5 conversations under any circumstance.

What happens if I never close them but keep re-using for ever? I don't use retention and both initiator and target are in the same machine.

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is OK. Conversations are designed to be long lived and be reused for years, if need be.

One drawback will be that the error handling and conversation closed case code in your app is probably never exercised, likely has bugs.